# Update for Unattended Updates Causes Problems

Tags: updates, appcenter

After installing the update that enables unattended updates, I am receiving a "Failed to Fetch Updates" message. Also as a result, when I try to use Synaptic Package Manager, I receive the message,

> E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades:14:
>   Malformed tag.

An additional side effect is that if I uninstall an app from the AppCenter and then try to reinstall it, I no longer receive a prompt for a password and hence I can no longer reinstall the app.

What can I do to remedy the situation and get this update for enabling unattended updates to behave properly? I am running Hera with Linux 5.3.0-40 kernel.

Answer (score 3):

To translate that: 
1. sudo open /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
2. remove one of the end quotation marks in line 13

```
"UbuntuESMApps:bionic-apps-security"";
```

-->

```
"UbuntuESMApps:bionic-apps-security";
```

3. save

to test you can run

```
sudo unattended-upgrades --dry-run -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Monsieur,
j'avait le même problème. Ma solution : Effacez dans le fichier « apt.conf.d » à la ligne 13 seulement un guillemet " et puis le résultat est : "UbuntuESMApps:bionic-apps-security";
D'après toutes les actualisations marchent.
Meilleurs salutations

Comment: I had no double quotes in line 13. Also, my line 13 reads: "UbuntuESM:bionic";